# Restoring Table row data after refreshing the page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I am having task that i have to move the selected row to top in table and when i refresh the page i want to restore the previous changes.

I completed the moveRow logic.

But i  am not getting how to restore the row data, please assist me for this.

Below is my code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script language="JavaScript">

    var whichrow = false;
    var TableLocation;        

    function thisrow(x)
    {
         TableLocation = x.sectionRowIndex;

    }
    function MoveUp()
    {
        var tablebody = document.getElementById('table1'); 
         if(TableLocation > 0)
         { 
             tablebody.moveRow(TableLocation, 1);
         }

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table id="table1" name="table1" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
   <tr id="tr3" onclick="thisrow(this)"> 
       <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
       <td><input type="text" name="address"></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="tr4" onclick="thisrow(this)"> 
       <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address"></td>
       <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1"></td>
   </tr >
    <tr id="tr5" onclick="thisrow(this)"> 
       <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="address"></td>
       <td ><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1"></td>
    </tr>  
</table>


<input type="button" value="move row up" onClick="MoveUp();"> 

</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Thanx in advance...
looking forword for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save your changes on the server to reload your page (you don't need to save on database, you can store it in the session and use use on the next page rendering). Then you can use your javascript to move up/down your rows.

I suggest you to put data-attributes in your html tags to order it in javascript or order on the server before rendering.